# .idea/compiler.xml in .gitignore?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, kotlin, gitignore

Whenever I `gradle build` my Spring app in IntelliJ, `compiler.xml` gets modified and shows up in my `git status`.

Is it safe to put compiler.xml file in .gitignore with the other `.idea/` files?

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it's all good. You can probably put .idea/* in .gitignore. I am currently working on a project in uni and we've had some startup issues with .idea/compiler.xml being changed back and forth, and I think it was because someone used java 11 when the rest of us used java 12. So be mindfull about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official support page:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

And the jetbrains ignore starting point file.
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/JetBrains.gitignore
Where they state the following:

```
# When using Gradle or Maven with auto-import, you should exclude module files,
# since they will be recreated, and may cause churn.  Uncomment if using
# .idea/compiler.xml
```

So, yeah, it should be ok to ignore compile.xml. But you should NOT ignore the whole .idea folder.